# Subgroups of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ which are $Aut(L)$ for some Lie structure

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

What is a sufficient condition for  a lie subgroup  $G$ of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$  to be the automorphism group of a Lie structure on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. In particular does $O(n)$ satisfies  this property?

Comment: What do you mean by 'Lie structure'?  Do you just mean the structure of a Lie algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: If you did mean the structure of a Lie algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the answer is 'yes' for $n=3$ and $G = \mathrm{SO}(3)$ (but 'no' for $\mathrm{O}(3)$ when $n=3$) and no for $G =\mathrm{SO}(n)$ and $\mathrm{O}(n)$ all other $n$.

Comment: @RobertBryant Could you please introduce a reference(book) for the reasons of the statements which you mentioned.